# I'm a Nigerian with Italian permit to stay, can I come to the UK without a visa?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens

Because I have been thinking on going to the UK for quite some time now, but I don't really know how to start the process.

Answer (score 1):

Check this page https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa, enter all the data that it asks and you'll have 100% correct answer.

Comment: Downvote dude, can you explain your decision?

Comment: Providing a link is fine as supplementary information, but you haven't actually answered the question.

Comment: I don't have any information about OP's visas or possible denials how can I answer his question?

Comment: If you do not have the information to answer the question, do not answer it. As so often there is enough information in the question that you can fill out the site and get an answer that would stand. If you do not answer, someone else will.